# Python: error in writing class

Tags: python, class

I want to write func and add that to class.
I use

```
import pandas as pd
import tldextract

domain = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['urls'] = ['ru.vk.com', 'eng.facebook.com', 'ru.ya.ru']
urls = df.urls.values.tolist()
class csv:
    def get_domain(self, list_url, list, df):
        self.list_url = list_url
        self.list = list
        self.df = df
        for i, url in enumerate(list_url):
            get_domain = tldextract.extract(url)
            subdomain = get_domain[0] + '.' + get_domain[1] + '.' + get_domain[2]
            if subdomain.startswith('.'):
                subdomain = subdomain[1:]
            elif subdomain.endswith('.'):
                subdomain = subdomain[:-1]
            elif subdomain.startswith('www.'):
                subdomain = subdomain[4:]
            list.append(subdomain)
        df['subdomain'] = list

df = csv()
df.get_domain(urls, domain, df)
```

I try to get domain from the urls, but I get error

```
AttributeError: csv instance has no attribute '__setitem__'
```

What I should change?

Comment: Why are you using a class here at all? It only has one method, and the three attributes could just as easily be local variables.

Comment: Hey stop using reserved names as your parameter names. `list` is a builtin in python.

Comment: Is it intentional that `self.list_url = list_url` and `self.list = list` only copy references to the original lists, these assignments do not create copies of the lists.  For that you need `copy.deepcopy` (or a hack with a slice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You named the variable that you use to create the `csv` instance `df`, same as the data frame item, by that making `df` refer to `csv` object and not panda dataframe. Then, when you try to call `get domain`, `df` refers to the class, that has no way to get a string indices, thus failing.

---

In short - change the variable name in the last 2 rows, like

```
csv_df = csv()
csv_df.get_domain(urls, domain, df)
```

---

By the way, It's not a mistake, but I'm pretty sure the last row on `get_domain` was supposed to be

```
self.df['subdomain'] = self.list
```

(Same goes for all variables all across the function, since you desire to change the class property and not the given variable).

And you shouldn't name a variable `list` or any other reserved keyword. Might cause issues.

Comment: I like the suggestion of not using a class, and only defining the method better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what else should you change, but you most certainly should NOT use the get_domain variable inside the get_domain method. Start with this, and then see if it solves anything.

(the get_domain function is on the second line of the class, and the get_domain variable is on the 6th line of the class)

Edit: and one more thing, the code in the method has no relevance whatsoever to the values in the... let's call it test data. It might be wrong or it might be right, but you'd have no idea.